# Warning ao instalar nodemon. Como resolver?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Instalei o nodemon com o seguinte comando

```
$ sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Recebi o seguinte erro:

```
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating 
system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
```

Qual a importancia desse erro? POsso despreza-lo? Como resolve-lo?

Estou rodando Ubunto 16.04 64.

Comment: Estás a usar o `nodemon` em desenvolvimento e não em produção certo? nesse caso, e se não tiveres problemas de recarregamento podes ignorar. É esse o caso?

Answer (score 1):

A dependência `fsevents` é destinada ao uso no OSX, de acordo com o [README do pacote no NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents).

Como seu sistema operacional é um Linux, você pode seguramente ignorar essa warning já que o `nodemon` não vai se utilizar dela mesmo. :)